# How to use a @State var placeholder of type func in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, state

Here is my code

```
import SwiftUI

struct DisablingButton: View {
    @State var text: String
    @State var action: <Type = some func> // what I should put here?
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action:
                        {action}, label:
                {
                    Text(text)
                        .frame(width: 90,height: 50).padding(.trailing, 50)
                            .cornerRadius(24)
                            .foregroundColor(.init(red: 50, green: 50, blue: 50))
                            .background(Color.init(#colorLiteral(red: 0.4673788197, green: 0.8577259761, blue: 0.2381303948, alpha: 1)))
                            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle.init())
                            .cornerRadius(24)
            })
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                
                
            }.padding(.trailing)
        }
    }
}
```

What I should put in place **Expected Type** to use this view in other views?

I tried to use
`@State var action: () -> Void` but there is an error
`Expression resolves to an unused function`

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because you don't call the function. Use `action()` inside your code.

My working example:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct DisablingButton: View {
    @State var text: String
    @State var action: () -> ()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {action()}, label:
                {
                    Text(text)
                        .frame(width: 90,height: 50).padding(.trailing, 50)
                            .cornerRadius(24)
                            .foregroundColor(.init(red: 50, green: 50, blue: 50))
                            .background(Color.init(#colorLiteral(red: 0.4673788197, green: 0.8577259761, blue: 0.2381303948, alpha: 1)))
                            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle.init())
                            .cornerRadius(24)
            })
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                
                
            }.padding(.trailing)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        DisablingButton(text: "Button", action: { print("debug output") })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

And even though this code works fine, do you really need a state for the action? Instead of `@State var action: () -> ()` a constant reference will also work: `let action: () -> ()`